# How to add SignOut link in My Account Dashboard listed option programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2

Actually,
 I am trying to add **signOut link** in My Dashboard end of the page  where other  links are listed  programmatically using magento 2.

can any one idea related it.

Comment: https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-customer-sign-out-link-in-my-account-navigation-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add **Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml** file in your theme folder and paste content below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        

        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation"><!--ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"-->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-logout-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Logout</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Add `translate="true"` on xml node of the label to make sure it can be translated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **customer_account.xml** file under your theme directory **/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Customer/layout/** and add the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns xsi="http://wwww3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/ete/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation"> 
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navagation-signout-link">
          <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Sign Out</argument>
          </arguments>
          </block>
     </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

Clean Magento Cache, Sign In, and navigate to the My Account. At the bottom of the Navigation menu, you have to see the **Sign Out** link as in the screen below.

[image]